# При авторизации приходит токен undefined, что делать?

Tags: typescript, nextjs

Вот сам код:

```
 const [authData, setAuthData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  // const router = useRouter();

  const submitForm = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + 20 * 1000);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://10.137.60.137:8000/api/accounts/login/",
        authData,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("token")}`,
          },
        }
      );
      const data = response.data;

      Cookies.set("token", data.jwt, {
        expires: date,
      });
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // alert("вы зашли");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Incorrect email or password");
    }
  };
```